# Monotouch can't find AudioFileOpenURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, audiotoolbox

I'm developing in monotouch and I found a code written in objectiveC that uses a class called 
AudioFileOpenURL. I can't seem to find this class in mono touch.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with monotouch, but have you imported `AudioToolbox` framework?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the `MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFile` namespace.

```
MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFile.Open(...);
```

or

```
using MonoTouch.AudioToolbox;
AudioFile.Open(...);
```

You can easily find these things out by typing AudioFile and then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in Visual Studio or ALT+RETURN in Xamarin Studio to trigger Intellisense and let it add the missing `using` statement.

Comment: @user958880 Don't forget to tick this reply if it helped you! Thanks!